# From a NSSegmentedControl to a label

Tags: cocoa, text, label, cells, nssegmentedcontrol

I'm new to Mac Programming, but i'm having some ideas for an application.
My question is: i have a NSSegmentedControl with 2 cells and i wanted to, if the cell number 1 is selected, write something on a label with, for example, a blue color.
How can i do this?
i'm sorry if this was already asked :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which element is selected from the `selectedSegment`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i need help about mac applications, not ios. but thanks anyways!

Comment: Updated with the NSSsegmentedController docs.  It's pretty much the same method, though.